# I can access my neighbour's powerline ethernet network. Does that mean he can steal my power?

Tags: security, powerline-networking

I was under the impression that the electrics in my totally normal semi-detached house were sufficiently isolated from my neighbours' that it was impossible for my powerline networking adapters to interfere with his. So I was very surprised to find my desktop PC using my neighbour's broadband connection, via my TP-Link AV500. Clearly there is not as much isolation as I had hoped.

The devices have a pair button on them, so I'm willing to believe that there is some security between them. But I'm now concerned that if my electrical circuits are not isolated enough to block the homeplug signal, then is it possible that they are also not isolated enough to prevent power theft?

Comment: I think you posted early. April 1st is still 3days away.

Comment: How do you know it's your neighbors network?

Comment: No, but you can leach his internet...

Comment: You should definitely Change your powerline Network Password! It Looks like your Adapters come with Password "HomePlugAV" (like most Powerline Adapters I know) which is insecure.

Answer (score 6):

He can't steal (meaningful amounts of) power that way.

Ethernet over powerline works similar to WiFi, except using the cable as wave conduction mechanism rather than the air.

What's happening here is that the network signal is traversing the power meters of your and their houses -  of course, the power meters are not (should not) be interested in this high frequency, very low current signal, so they will not count it.